# Making Variable read from XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

Based on some of my previous questions I have put together the following:

```
var xml = "<root><Data><Info>data</Info></Data></root>";

            var xmlString = (from data in XElement.Parse(xml).Descendants("Data")
                             where data.Descendants().Any()
                             select data.Descendants().First().Value).FirstOrDefault();

            var fileString = File.ReadAllText(@"1.txt");

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", fileString == xmlString ? 1 : 0);
```

The above is supposed to load a **specific part** of an xml, load a text file, and compare the two. Unfortunatly for me, I am new to C# and some of its concepts, and am unsure of how to make the `var xml = "<root><Data><Seperator>data</Seperator></Data></root>";` read from a specific xml file in the same directory.

I know I can use:

```
    FileStream stream = new FileStream("1234.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
while(reader.Read())
{
  Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
}
```

if I were to have 1234.xml and wanted to output it to the console, but I don't know how to load the contents of the file in a way that the defined variable xml is able to read it.

EDIT:

Based on the posts below, I have tried to use the following, but it is returning blank in console:

```
  using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("2.xml"))
     {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
               if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
               {
                    if (reader.Name.ToLower() == "data")
                    {
                        string xml = reader.ReadOuterXml();

                        var xmlString = (from data in XDocument.Parse(xml).Elements()
                                                 select data.Elements().First().Value).FirstOrDefault();

                         xmlString = xmlString.Replace("\n", "").Trim();

                        var fileString = File.ReadAllText(@"8.txt");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", fileString == xmlString ? 1 : 0);
                     }
                }
           }

  }
```

Edit 2:

The XML file is a hash value and a signature (I am only trying to grab and compare the Hash and its value):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<root>-<Data><Info>Hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Info></Data>-<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">-<SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>-<Reference URI="">-<Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>GHOSJRUqcHnZ3M090/5/KhvghyQ=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>oib+LAXqJshDFm3YM63qkSsJxxF+t0uahGax8tLrjSPJUjW045iYvB4LJCgMeF9oxatbWnVB9hGbvtVnl4iewJDL3kjnjvot5CLozMOaIGJgdys5MP8ncx771itANTm8wi8KgnqVjGjvTakEmcdwcSdRXuCP1WGOwuXm5StkY8Q=</SignatureValue></Signature></root>
```

Comment: You can't have a `-` before the root element definition.

Comment: Your xml file is not well formed. there are unwanted hyphens in it. you may want to remove them first. check my edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your requirements are; but based on your question and comments it looks like you have a xml document like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Data>
   <Info>
    data
   </Info>
  </Data>
  <Data>
   <Seperator>
    other data
   </Seperator>
  </Data>
</root>
```

You want to read values from the first element within the `<Data></Data>` tags (child element name can vary, like in the example it can be `<Info></Info>` or `<Seperator></Seperator>`

Here is the solution (which will get the values '`data`', '`other data`')

```
 using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("1234.xml"))
 {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
           if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
           {
                if (reader.Name.ToLower() == "data")
                {
                    string xml = reader.ReadOuterXml();

                    var xmlString = (from data in XDocument.Parse(xml).Elements()
                                             select data.Elements().First().Value).FirstOrDefault();

                     xmlString = xmlString.Replace("\n", "").Trim();

                     // Your other operations
                 }
            }
       }
  }
```

**EDIT**

Your xml data is not well formatted (there are unwanted hyphens (-) before elements). If it is well formed my code is working. Your xml file should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
 <Data>
  <Info>Hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Info>
 </Data>
 <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <Reference URI="">
      <Transforms>
         <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
       </Transforms>
       <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
       <DigestValue>GHOSJRUqcHnZ3M090/5/KhvghyQ=</DigestValue>
     </Reference>
   </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>oib+LAXqJshDFm3YM63qkSsJxxF+t0uahGax8tLrjSPJUjW045iYvB4LJCgMeF9oxatbWnVB9hGbvtVnl4iewJDL3kjnjvot5CLozMOaIGJgdys5MP8ncx771itANTm8wi8KgnqVjGjvTakEmcdwcSdRXuCP1WGOwuXm5StkY8Q=</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, writing so much code is much appreciated, but as I posted above, something isn't working. If you could take a look, it would be Greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you share the contents of your 'xml' and 'txt' files ('1234.xml' and '8.txt')

Comment: I have modified my post. Your XML file is not well formed. look for the edited format in my post. then if you run the code you will get 'Hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for xmlString variable

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to populate a string variable with the contents of the file, try

```
var xml = File.ReadAllText("1234.xml");
```

(same thing you do with "1.txt")

Make sure you are

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to populate the variable xml with the specific line in the xml file "<root><Data><Info>data</Info></Data></root>"

Comment: with the "data" in between "info" changing depending on the xml file, so the script would load an xml file with this file structure, look at the data on this line, and compare the data to a text file

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file by using either an XDocument or XElement and `Load`ing it:

For example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("1234.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, but the variable "xml" that defines a specific line of the xml doesn't seem to pick up on it, any idea why this could be? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To load the file from the same directory as the executable try this:

```
string path = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]), 
    "1234.xml");

XElement xml = XElement.Load(path);
```

If you care you can use this library to get the hash value: https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/ like:

```
string result = xml.XPathElement("//Data[*]").Descendants().First().Value;
```

The `//Data[*]` means descendant Data nodes with any child nodes, which you have in your equation.

But if you know your data will be in the Data/Info node (still using the library):

```
string info = xml.Get("Data/Info", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below codes.......

The XML file named Persons.xml you have to use.....

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Persons>
      <Person>
        <Name>abcd</Name>
        <City>Kolkata</City>
        <Sex>Female</Sex>
      </Person>
    </Persons>
```

now to add data to this XML file you have to create a form, where you can have three fields Name, City and Sex field with corresponding text boxes and two button to **Add** data to the XML file and **Read** to read data from this XML file.

Now double click on the **Add** button and write the below code...

```
    protected void butAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtName.Text == "" || txtCity.Text == "" || txtSex.Text == "")
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Please complete the form.";
            }
            else
            {
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Persons.xml"));

                xmlDoc.Element("Persons").Add(new XElement("Person", new XElement("Name", txtName.Text),
                new XElement("City", txtCity.Text), new XElement("Sex", txtSex.Text)));
                lblStatus.Text = "Data successfully added to XML file.";
                xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("Persons.xml"));

            }
         }
        catch
            { 
                lblStatus.Text = "Sorry, unable to process request. Please try again.";
            }
      }
```

Again double click on the Read button and write the below codes to read data....

```
     protected void butRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Persons.xml"));

        var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("Person")
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = person.Element("Name").Value,
                          City = person.Element("City").Value,
                          Sex = person.Element("Sex").Value,
                      };

        litResults.Text = "";
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            litResults.Text = litResults.Text + "Name: " + person.Name + "<br />";
            litResults.Text = litResults.Text + "City: " + person.City + "<br />";
            litResults.Text = litResults.Text + "Sex: " + person.Sex + "<br /><br />";
        }

        if (litResults.Text == "")
            litResults.Text = "No Results.";
    }
```